# Easy to Deploy 2 server setup on AWS

Tags: magento2, nginx, hosting, deployment, aws

My client wishes to make a simple 2 server magento setup, one for the database and one for the webserver.  Most AMI out there or AWS deployments are much much more complicated (and expensive!) and not really needed yet by us at this time.  Deploy4me had a great solution that was just that for us, but as per my correspondence with them they have since taken it down due to errors in mysql they said it will be up again eventually but it's probably best I deploy manually if time is an issue (which it is).

I have searched far and wide for hours, looking at vagrant, docker, puphpet, puppet, AMI's, and AWS documentation in regards to deployment and magento, blogs for setups by hand, install scripts, blogs about beanstalk on amazon and so on and so on, without finding one simple solution yet for deploying just a LEMP stack with mysql on a separate machine, outside deploy4me, which as I stated is not offering that service at this time.  So, that's why I'm posting here, in hopes anyone here might know of some deployment method with that fairly popular and well recommended setup included.  Which is why I'm somewhat confused as to why finding that setup is so hard.  I do have the knowledge to build it from scratch, but it's time consuming to do right and will cost my client unneeded dev hours.  I could go with a full scaling solution, but I'm guessing he'd be upset at the cost of some of these 5+ server setup solutions and has expressly forbade a single server solution.

Comment: Why are you/they set on AWS? Why multiple servers?

Comment: I'm not sure they are completely set on AWS, but several guides online recommended them, as well as a 2 server setup (one for database and one for webserver).  His friend also has a setup just like that for magento he is very pleased with so that is the reasoning for AWS and multiple servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have Magento 2 interactive installation script for Debian 11, install LEMP + complete webstack, WEBMIN control panel, some security tools like CSF Firewall, ELK stack, and lots of other tools and apps.

you can test it:

```
curl -sL https://magenx.sh > magenx.sh
```

it will deploy everything in less than ~15 minutes.
if you need you can install MariaDB on a separate server and move/connect your database there.

but i really think you should go to digitalocean or soyoustart,
very cheap for small setups.

Comment: Thank you for making such a great tool available for free!  It installed everything, but the config files didn't download for some reason.  I went with Digital Ocean, and did a centos 7 droplet there.  Nginx doesn't start b/c the config file is blank, varnish started by hmm.  Just letting you know I'll try to solve it on my own if you don't reply thanks.

Comment: yes, this is fixed now, config path was wrong

Comment: Thanks that worked, the other issue too was I would try to do the script steps again and it would put another entry for my store name in the .mascm_index file, which was making a lot of the sed and other parts of the script fail by trying to put the store name in, on multiple lines.  The best solution was just cleaning up by rebuilding the droplet but if I had stuff already on the server that obviously isn't an option.