# Best server setup for Magento 2

Tags: magento2, server-setup

I'm trying to setup a server for Magento 2.
I'm following through the official [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html), but it's patchy at best.
For example, as of writing there is no direct method of installing PHP7.02 on Centos other than following their [non officially recommended method](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/php-centos.html#php-centos-7) of using the IUS repository.

Is there a recommended server setup for Magento 2 that we could follow along and easily spin up servers?

The answer I'm looking for would include

- Which OS is better (CentOS, Ubuntu, Debian)
- Which web server is better (Apache 2.2 or 2.4, nginx 1.8 or later)
- Which Database is better (MySQL 5.6, MariaDB or Percona)
- What PHP version (5.5, 5.6, 7.02, 7.06)
- PHP libraries (would include the ones listed by [Magento](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html))
- Additional PHP components and settings, like PHP OPcache and `memory_limit`
- Mail server (Magento mentions MTA or an SMTP server)
- Anything else like Redis, Varnish, Memcached etc

Ideally, once I figure out all of the above, I can then write a bash script to easily spin up Magento2 instances.

I am not looking for an out of the box one line command to install Magento2, rather I'm looking for a recommended stack starting with the OS and down.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy to Deploy 2 server setup on AWS](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/135615/easy-to-deploy-2-server-setup-on-aws)

Comment: @MagenX the OP on the thread you referenced is looking for a one command install script, I'm looking for best practices all along the stack. The script you provide in your answer assumes that the user is on CentOs 7

Comment: the answer that you are looking for ...

Comment: Every once in a while a question like this pops up here on Magento SE. Of course it is logical that one would question this, but unfortunately this question is not right for the SE Q&A format. Answers to this question would be highly subjective and very localized. So dozens of answers could and would be given and none of them would be 100% right and almost none of them 100% wrong. It would lead more to discussion than Q&A. I'd suggest to check the Magento forums: https://community.magento.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?advanced=false&allow_punctuation=false&q=best%20server%20setup

Answer (score -1):

Which OS is better (Ubuntu)

Which web server is better (Apache 2)

Which Database is better (MySQL 5.6)

What PHP version (7.1)

Install Varnish.

Comment: According to Magento dev docs, PHP 7.1 is not supported

Comment: I already using it and it's working for me.

Comment: If you choose 7.0 than it's also ok.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out the best way, why would you recommend PHP7.01 over PHP7.02

Comment: @MayankZalavadia for your knowledge you may refer 
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/139634/magento-2-1-1-not-compatibile-with-php-7-1-0

Comment: @Magento2Learner Learner You just trying to install M2.2.2 with PHP 7.1 and then tell me because in my pc Magento 2.2.2 it's installed and it's working.

Comment: @Magento2Learner I am not going to argue with you. Just tell you it's working for me. So, you just try.

Comment: @Haim Please check http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html#php

Comment: magento 2 works on php 7.1 and mysql 5.7 ...

Comment: my favorite stack for magento 2.3 is centos 7, nginx, Percona 5.7, php 7.1